# React error on the staticContext prop

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I followed the documentation of `react-router-dom` for setting up the server-side rendering: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering, but now I got:

```
React does not recognize the `staticContext` prop on a DOM element
```

I'm using `react v16` and the latest version of `react-router-dom`

Comment: Add some code that you have tried!

Comment: Found the issue, it came from another package that I was using.

Comment: @HaJa You're allowed to answer your own question. What was the issue?

Comment: @HaJa It'd be helpful for the community if you share your solution.